# Strange bug in ModSecurity with the rule 950901

Tags: proxy, apache, mod-security

I have a classic ModSecurity configuration (apt-get...)

```
SecRuleEngine Off

SecPcreMatchLimit 1000
SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 1000

SecAction "phase:1,t:none,nolog,pass, \
setvar:'tx.allowed_methods=GET HEAD POST OPTIONS', \
setvar:'tx.allowed_request_content_type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded multipart/form-data text/xml application/xml application/x-amf', \
setvar:'tx.allowed_http_versions=HTTP/0.9 HTTP/1.0 HTTP/1.1', \
setvar:'tx.restricted_extensions=.asa/ .asax/ .ascx/ .axd/ .backup/ .bak/ .bat/ .cdx/ .cer/ .cfg/ .cmd/ .com/ .config/ .conf/ .cs/ .csproj/ .csr/ .dat/ .db/ .dbf/ .dll/ .dos/ .htr/ .htw/ .ida/ .idc/ .idq/ .inc/ .ini/ .key/ .licx/ .lnk/ .log/ .mdb/ .old/ .pass/ .pdb/ .pol/ .printer/ .pwd/ .resources/ .resx/ .sql/ .sys/ .vb/ .vbs/ .vbproj/ .vsdisco/ .webinfo/ .xsd/ .xsx/', \
setvar:'tx.restricted_headers=/Proxy-Connection/ /Lock-Token/ /Content-Range/ /Translate/ /via/ /if/'"
```

And I get this error:

```
--70244300-A--
[04/Jun/2014:17:14:29 +0200] U4831X8AAAEAAFDVH5IAAAAS X.X.X.X 58274 Y.Y.Y.Y 80
--70244300-B--
GET /images/login_bg.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: myHost.local
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0
Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://myHost.local/css/main.css
Cookie: symfony=9a09bb2c53df046aae0ed80c501c9585
Connection: keep-alive

--70244300-F--
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Wed, 05 Nov 2008 14:54:40 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 31429
Content-Type: image/jpeg
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
Connection: close

--70244300-E--

--70244300-H--
Message: Rule 7f36b7b712b0 [id "950901"][file "/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"][line "77"] - Execution error - PCRE limits exceeded (-8): (null).
Apache-Handler: proxy-server
Stopwatch: 1401894869729902 23796 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1401894869729902 23796; combined=9162, p1=144, p2=8864, p3=3, p4=82, p5=67, sr=0, sw=2, l=0, gc=0
Response-Body-Transformed: Dechunked
Producer: ModSecurity for Apache/2.6.6 (http://www.modsecurity.org/).
Server: Apache

--70244300-Z--
```

The strange rule:

```
#
# -=[ SQL Tautologies ]=-
#
SecRule REQUEST_COOKIES|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|REQUEST_FILENAME|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/* "(?i:([\s'\"`´’‘\(\)]*)?([\d\w]+)([\s'\"`´’‘\(\)]*)?(?:=|<=>|r?like|sounds\s+like|regexp)([\s'\"`´’‘\(\)]*)?\2|([\s'\"`´’‘\(\)]*)?([\d\w]+)([\s'\"`´’‘\(\)]*)?(?:!=|<=|>=|<>|<|>|\^|is\s+not|not\s+like|not\s+regexp)([\s'\"`´’‘\(\)]*)?(?!\6)([\d\w]+))" \
        "phase:2, \
        rev:'2.2.5', \
        capture, \
        multiMatch, \
        t:none, \
        t:urlDecodeUni, \
        t:replaceComments, \
        ctl:auditLogParts=+E, \
        block, \
        msg:'SQL Injection Attack', \
        id:'950901', \
        logdata:'%{TX.0}', \
        severity:'2', \
        tag:'WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION', \
        tag:'WASCTC/WASC-19', \
        tag:'OWASP_TOP_10/A1', \
        tag:'OWASP_AppSensor/CIE1', \
        tag:'PCI/6.5.2', \
        setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.msg}', \
        setvar:tx.sql_injection_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score}, \
        setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score}, \
        setvar:tx.%{rule.id}-WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION-%{matched_var_name}=%{tx.0}"
```

I get this error for every request... Why !?

**EDIT:**
My `SecRuleEngine` is `Off` in my global settings BUT it's set to `DetectionOnly` foreach VHOST.

Comment: mod_security, says it all. happy time-wasting on tuning your mod_sec_rules. btw, it's not a bug, its a feature

Comment: Your ModSecurity Configuration will not work because as per your configuration `SecRuleEngine Off` its off.

Comment: Oups ! It's Off in global setting but it's DetectionOnly in my individual Host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at the debug logs yet to see how these config settings work, but I think your problem is the "SecPcreMatchLimit" and "SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion" settings being enabled in your CRS_10 file(s). I've recently enabled them and see similar matches in our logs. It's about the only config settings I've changed after updating ModSec binaries.

Either try setting the numbers very high (100k-1M to start), or disable (comment the lines out) and restart Apache. (I'd recommend disabling.)

Comment: Thanks !
I have changed my `SecPcreMatchLimit` and `SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion` to 3000.